# Roman numerals in Python using "re" module

Tags: python, regex

I'm working along on [this page](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/roman_numerals.html) and continuing the code to cover the 10's place. My "pattern" is:

```
>>> pattern = '^M?M?M?(CM?|CD?|D?C?C?C?)(XC?|XL?|L?X?X?X?)$'
```

If I remove the carat (^) from the front of the "pattern", then strings like 'hat' will find a match:

```
>>> pattern = 'M?M?M?(CM?|CD?|D?C?C?C?)(XC?|XL?|L?X?X?X?)$'    
>>> print re.search(pattern,'hat')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004ba360>
```

but when I leave the carat in the front, then it works fine and 'hat' doesn't find a match. What does the carat do and why does 'hat' find a match?

Comment: See [Regular Expression HOWTO - More metacharacters](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex#more-metacharacters).

Answer (score 4):

If you actually print what it's matching, ie:

```
print re.search(pattern,"hat").group()
```

You'll see nothing, this is because it's matching to the empty string: `""`.  In your regex, every expression ends with `?` indicating 0 or 1 of whatever came before it.  Without the `^` at the front, your regex will match anything.  It essentially boils down to: `pattern = '$'`, which again matches everything.

The `^` means "starts with."  When you put the `^` in, `"hat"` doesn't match, because it doesn't adhere to any of your requirements and does not start with `""`; however, if you put `""` in lieu of `"hat"`, you will get a match.